# -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] crash in iOS 14

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios14

We encountered an OpenGL related crash on ios14. It has nothing to do with the application background. The vast majority of crashes occurred on IOS 14 low-end devices, and it is not clear how to solve them.

The only possible clue is that the crash may have something to do with opening the WebView.

Monitor Type:    Unix Signal
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0x00000001c7517414
Crashed Thread:  0

```
Pthread id: 10322737
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         pthread_kill + 272
2   libsystem_c.dylib               abort + 104
3   AppleMetalGLRenderer            GLDContextRec::flushContextInternal() + 852
4   GLEngine                        gliPresentViewES_Exec + 188
5   OpenGLES                        -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 76
6   myapp                           -[EJCanvasContextWebGLScreen present] (EJCanvasContextWebGLScreen.m:142)
7   QuartzCore                      CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 664
8   QuartzCore                      display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 280
9   CoreFoundation                  __CFMachPortPerform + 176
10  CoreFoundation                  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
11  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 596
12  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopRun + 2360
13  CoreFoundation                  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
14  GraphicsServices                GSEventRunModal + 164
15  UIKitCore                       -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
16  UIKitCore                       UIApplicationMain + 168
17  myapp                           main (main.m:36)
18  libdyld.dylib                   start + 4
```

Comment: Have you fixed this problem, and how? thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm 100% sure presentRenderBuffer works fine in iOS14.

According to the error message, it seems like a thread issue.

In my case, I use a queue to detail with all of the OpenGL things.

```
dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        // All of the OpenGL things
        [self bindCurrentRenderBuffer];
        [self presentRenderBuffer];
    });
```

You can see my OpenGL project in Github: [IRPlayer](https://github.com/irons163/IRPlayer)